# Running all tests with Quickbuild

Tags: maven, junit, quickbuild

I have experience with Jenkins and I am used to that, that it runs all tests through no matter if a test is failing. At the end I have a complete list of failed tests including all Maven submodules.

Is it possible to reach the same behaviour with Quickbuild?

Comment: If you look [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html), you'll see that maven has a fail-at-end option, isn't that what you need? It's maven behaviour, not Jenkins.

Comment: If a module has a failed test, then the rest of the tests inside that module will not be executed. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about that, I think it'll still execute the rest. You'll have to try to find out for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In maven world quickbuild seems to do nothing special. It just uses the default behaviour of maven. As soon as there is a test failure, the multi-module project build will stop at the current module.

If you want to build everything, you have to add this to your command:

```
-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

This way all modules will be built, still quickbuild will find the failed tests in the reports.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want to achieve is the default behavior in QB. See screenshot from my tests:
[image: QuickBuild Step Status]

Although the first test case was failed rest of the test cases were executed.

Comment: hmm. Ok. Then it must be some setting in our QB server.